# NestJs email failed to send with ejs template dynamic data

Tags: ejs, nestjs, nodemailer

I am trying to send email in Nestjs framework using @nestjs-modules/mailer nodemailer. Email are working fine with normal text but when is setup to use EJS template for email body its stoped working.
I use [https://nest-modules.github.io/mailer/docs/mailer.html][1] for reference below are my source code.
App.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { EjsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/ejs.adapter';
import { join } from 'path';
const path = join(__dirname, '../../../apps/api/src/app/template');

@Module({
  imports: [MailerModule.forRoot({
    transport: environment.SmtpDetails,
    defaults: {
      from: environment.SmtpEmail,
    },
    template: {
      dir: path,
      adapter: new EjsAdapter(),
      options: {
        strict: true,
      },
    },
  })
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Email Service

```
import { Injectable, BadGatewayException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
@Injectable()
export class EmailService {
    constructor(private readonly mailerService: MailerService) { }

    async sendNotificationEmail(emailTo: string, data: object) {
        console.log(__dirname);
        try {
            const emailData = await this.mailerService.sendMail({
                to: emailTo,
                from: 'user@test.com',
                subject: 'Testing Nest Mailermodule with template',
                template: 'notification', 
                context: {  // Data to be sent to template engine.
                    "code": 'cf1a3f828287',
                    "username": 'john doe',
                },
            });
            if (emailData) return emailData;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            throw new BadGatewayException('Email send failed');
        }
    }
}
```

Notification.ejs

```
<p>Welcome , your activation code is <%= code %></p>
```

I am getting **code is not defined** error.

Answer (score 15):

There are two approaches to solving this problem:

1. Use the EJS `locals` object

Context properties are passed to your compiled EJS templates in an object called locals. If you update your template variables to use the `locals` prefix, those values can be resolved and substituted:

```
<p>Welcome, your activation code is <%= locals.code %></p>
```

2. Disable strict mode

EJS strict mode is creating the need to use the `locals` object in your templates instead of the plain variable names from your context. You could instead just disable that setting in your NestJS MailerModule instantiation:

```
options: {
  strict: false,
},
```

Comment: You saved my last hair.

Answer (score 2):

in main.ts try "app.setViewEngine('ejs');"